# Recorrer un rango de elementos con jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Cómo implementar una funcion para recorrer un rango de elementos por ejemplo comenzar desde el id p2 hasta el id p7 y modificar el texto de cada uno de los elementos que que recorri, no tengo ni las mas remota idea de como hacer eso. si me pudiesen dar una idea o facilitar un ejemplo de verdad lo agradeceria

```
<ul class="caja">
        <li id="p1">Parte 1</li>
        <li id="p2">Parte 2</li>
        <li id="p3">Parte 3</li>
        <li id="p4">Parte 4</li>
        <li id="p5">Parte 5</li>
        <li id="p6">Parte 6</li>
        <li id="p7">Parte 7</li>
        <li id="p8">Parte 8</li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para hacerlo puedes usar la función `each()` de jQuery, de tal manera que recorras los elementos dentro del tag `<ul>`, o a través de la clase que este tag tiene:

```js
var element = $('.caja li').length; //obtienes el total de elementos dentro del tag ul con clase caja
$( ".caja li" ).each(function( index ) {
  if(index > 0 && index < element-1){ //condicion para excluir el primer y el ultimo elemento de la lista
    $( this ).html(index+" otro"); //cambias el texto dentro de los elementos li
    //console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).text() );
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Each</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="caja">
        <li id="p1">Parte 1</li>
        <li id="p2">Parte 2</li>
        <li id="p3">Parte 3</li>
        <li id="p4">Parte 4</li>
        <li id="p5">Parte 5</li>
        <li id="p6">Parte 6</li>
        <li id="p7">Parte 7</li>
        <li id="p8">Parte 8</li>
    </ul>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(".caja li").each(function(index){
    if (index > 0 ){ // ignorando el primer elemento cuando index es igual 0
        var element = $(this); // <-- en la variable element tienes tu elemento
        console.log(element.text());
    }
});
```

```html
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- HTML -->
<ul class="caja">
  <li id="p1">Parte 1</li>
  <li id="p2">Parte 2</li>
  <li id="p3">Parte 3</li>
  <li id="p4">Parte 4</li>
  <li id="p5">Parte 5</li>
  <li id="p6">Parte 6</li>
  <li id="p7">Parte 7</li>
  <li id="p8">Parte 8</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Listo, lo puse en español

Answer (score 1):

Las otras soluciones pueden funcionar, pero no son dinámicas, yo crearía una función donde pueda manejar los límites del rango (según el enunciado) y donde pueda asignar el selector también, de forma tal que pueda reutilizar el código.

El ejemplo sencillo está a continuación, el cual puede ser mejorado:

```js
function modificarRango(selector, inicio = 1, final) {
  for (var i = inicio; i <= final; i++) {
   $(selector + ":nth-child(" + i + ")").html('Mi nuevo texto');
  }
}
modificarRango(".caja li", 2, 7);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Each</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="caja">
        <li id="p1">Parte 1</li>
        <li id="p2">Parte 2</li>
        <li id="p3">Parte 3</li>
        <li id="p4">Parte 4</li>
        <li id="p5">Parte 5</li>
        <li id="p6">Parte 6</li>
        <li id="p7">Parte 7</li>
        <li id="p8">Parte 8</li>
    </ul>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```